# Wordpress caching - template issue

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

Using the latest version of WP (4.7.1) and no matter how many times I clear the cache and disable my caching plugins, one solitary page refuses to refresh. Every other page and file I update plays ball but "post-meta.php" refuses to obey.

I've added `<?php nocache_headers() ?>` to the top of the page and used a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers) among numerous others similar in nature.

Does anyone know why the server would constantly dish up a cached version of only one page?

Comment: Just to confirm, there is only one (1) version of `post-meta.php` across the theme?

Comment: Yes, correct...